# ''pgfkeysvalueof" in "append after command"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzset

With the following code, I was trying to override the default `bcol=red` with `bcol=green`, but that apparently does not work (the initial value is used in both cases). Is there a reasonable fix to make this idea (of adding a node controlled by a key passed to another node) work?

Note that I simplified my original example -- I have more complex shapes, one subordinate to the other, and both taking multiple parameters.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  bbox/.style={
    draw,
    append after command={node[fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bcol},at=(\tikzlastnode.north east)] {}}
  }
}

\tikzset{%
  bcol/.initial=red,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [bbox, draw] {};
  \node [bbox, xshift=15pt, bcol=green, draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has not so much to do with Ti*k*Z but with TeX grouping. That is, you cannot set the color inside the local group of the node. One of many ways to avoid this problem is

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  bbox/.style={
    draw,
    append after command={[#1]
    node[fill/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bcol},at=(\tikzlastnode.north east)] {}}
  }
}

\tikzset{%
  bcol/.initial=red,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [bbox, draw] {};
  \node [bbox={bcol=green}, xshift=15pt, draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! This nearly works with my original example, except that I get ```I do not know the key '/tikz/0' and I am going to ignore it``` unless I explicitly write ```bbox={}``` instead of just ```bbox``` as above. Any ideas, why this could happen?

Comment: @Sergey For me your original code `\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [bbox, draw] {};
  \node [bbox, xshift=15pt, bcol=green, draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}` does not produce an error when embedded in the document I show. That is, I do not know how to reproduce the error message you got.

Comment: Yes, with the above example, your solution works perfectly!